# How to count how many characters in a NSString up till a semicolon

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string value inside a `NSDictionary` that looks something like this

```
Rule = "K-------;-KKCT---";
```

So If I do something like this

```
NSString *tempString = [NSString alloc] init];
tempString = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Rule"];
```

tempString now has the follwing value "K-------;-KKCT---", I would like to then know how to count how many characters there are up to the semicolon in this case 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method of `NSString` is what you are looking for

`- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`

This will get the "range" of the first instance of the string you provide (in this case a semicolon)

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
NSString *tempString = myDictionary[@"Rule"];
NSUInteger count = [tempString rangeOfString:@";"].location;
if (count == NSNotFound) {
    count = 0;
}
```

Note that you should not allocate an empty string just to assign the variable another value from the dictionary.

If there is no semicolon in the string, the result will be the special value of `NSNotFound`. The above code converts this to a count of 0. Adjust this logic as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

```
NSArray *subStrings = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
int firstStringLength = [[subStrings objectAtIndex: 0] length];
```

If you need to find the length of all of the substrings, you would just loop through the array.